# Implementing methods from an Angular 4 service in two different components

Tags: angular

I have a service that I use in 2 diff components: one on buttons from a paginations and second in sidebar. Those 2 components are on the same level.
The problem is that on buttons components the methods works, but if I use them on sidebar don't work.

The Service

```
public navigate(action: string) {
 if (typeof this.ACTIONS[action] === 'undefined')
 return;

 let shift = this.ACTIONS[action];
 this.setCurrent(shift);

 const curr = this.getCurrent();
 this.activeIndex = curr.index;
 return this.router.navigate([curr.name]);
}

public setDisableFirst() {
 const curr = this.getCurrent();
 if(curr.index == 0) {
  return true;
 }
}

public setDisableLast() {
 const curr = this.getCurrent();
 return ((curr.index + 1) == (this._pages.length)) ? true : false;
}

public setActiveIndex() {
 const curr = this.getCurrent();
 return 'done-' + curr.index;

}
```

Buttons

```
 public disableFirst() {
  return this.PrevNextService.setDisableFirst();
 }

 public disableLast() {
  return this.PrevNextService.setDisableLast();
 }

 <button type="button" (click)="navigate('PREV')" [disabled]="disableFirst()">
 <button type="button" (click)="navigate('NEXT')" [disabled]="disableLast()">
```

Sidebar

```
 public activeClasss() { 
  return this.PrevNextService.setActiveIndex();
 }


 <div class="list-group-wrapper"  [ngClass]="activeClasss()">
```

If I console log in the Service this `const curr = this.getCurrent();` inside the methods: navigate, setDisableFirst, setDisableLast, I get the exactly page number(1,2,3, etc) that I am when I click next or back from buttons component.

The last method from Service, setActiveIndex, uses the same variables like in the methods from above. Here, in the Service, if console log `const curr = this.getCurrent();` I get only the first(1) page that I'm now. If I keep clicking on next or prev buttons, this const stays the same(1).

I use Angular 4. Can someone please give an idea why I get this behavior?

Comment: What does your `this.getCurrent()` method look like?

Comment: Gives me the actual page that I'm on. In constructor I have `this._current = this._pages.find((page) => {
      return this.router.url === page.name;
    });` and then I declare the function: `public getCurrent() {
  return this._current;
 }`

Comment: What does_pages.find() do? Please provide more relevant code.

Comment: _pages is an array and with find checks if the url is the same with the page name from the _pages array. Gives me back something like: `{name: "../page1", index: 0}`

Comment: Please provide more relevant code if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you registering your service? Do you have it in a providers array of one of your modules? Something like the `ProductService` shown below?

Do you have it registered in more then one module? Or also in a component?

For a service to work correctly as a singleton its provider needs to be registered in only one place via the providers array as shown below.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProductListComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ProductService
  ]
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

Comment: Sidebar `@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss'],
  providers: [PrevNextService]
})` and Buttons `@Component({
  selector: 'app-trade-buttons',
  templateUrl: './trade-btn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trade-btn.component.scss'],
  providers: [PrevNextService]
})` , both components use the same service PrevNextService. And I have it in app.module on prividers

Comment: You were right Deborah. Because I used providers array in each components with the same service, in each comp was a diff instance. So to have the same instance in all components I had  add it only in app.module, in providers.